# How to specify DATETIME format for a database connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord, unixodbc, tiny-tds

Currently I connect to a MSSQL database by `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` on top of `dbd-odbc` and `tiny_tds`.

INSERT is working, except for `DATETIME` field.

The datetime field returned from a SELECT:

```
rows = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows("SELECT * from customer")
```

in the result:

```
rows.first[5]
=> Wed Jan 11 00:00:00 UTC 1984
```

It gives an error if I use the same DATETIME value to INSERT a new row:

> ODBC::Error: 22008 (241) [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Syntax error
>   converting datetime from character string.

Where can I specify how `DATETIME` field are formatted?

Answer (score 0):

What you are inserting is a `String`. You have specified `TIMESTAMP` datatype in `MsSQL`. You have to match datatype in both `program` and `database`. Either change your `MsSQL` to `Varchar` datatype  or in your program take `date` datatype.